# ¿Cuál es el etiquetado para preguntas de conceptos de programación en general?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Me parece que la pregunta [¿En que casos se puede utilizar Negación lógica bit a bit, Negación unitaria?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38992/83) está bien formulada. Sin embargo, sus etiquetas no tienen relación con la pregunta en sí, ya que es un tema que no pertenece a un lenguaje específico ni tampoco algo exclusivo de un paradigma de programación como el funcional.

Quise cambiar las etiquetas, sin embargo no supe cuál debería ir. ¿Cómo debería etiquetarse este tipo de preguntas? ¿O simplemente no aplican como pregunta permitida en SOes?

Comment: Cuando la pregunta no es acerca de un lenguaje de programación específico, se usa la etiqueta [tag:lenguaje-agnóstico]. Sin embargo, eso no contesta a tu pregunta "sobre conceptos de programación en general".

Comment: @Mariano sin embargo la descripción de la etiqueta que mencionas coincide con lo que buscaba: *Esta etiqueta indica que la pregunta versa sobre cuestiones generales de programación que no dependen de ningún lenguaje en concreto*. Gracias

Comment: creo que se deberían reemplazar las etiquetas de lenguajes por esa, pero quizás también se deba etiquetar con otra, y no publiqué como respuesta por si hay una propuesta para agrupar este tipo de preguntas bajo una etiqueta que no estoy considerando